# Leaflet Js ,Draw Polygon?

Tags: leaflet, draw, drawable, leaflet-draw

I'm trying to code javascript for the first time, I want to add a few buttons and have the user draw Polygon,line,
can you help please

Comment: Go to the leaflet website, then see the list of plugins.

Comment: I am new to learning java script. I can't figure out how to write the function, can you help me as a code please.